# Conditional if statement / is_page not working in WordPress 3.0

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've tried a number of variations and I know this works when I put in is_home even though that's not what I'm trying to achieve but it displays it on every page.... if I try anything else like is_front_page or like what I have in the example below which is what I'm actually trying to achieve then it doesn't (work!). Can anyone help please?

```
<?php if (is_page('about')) { ?>
    <div id="testimonial-block" class="sidebar-block clearfix">
    <h4>Testomonials</h4>
    <p>"I feel so much more motivated and in control of my life. The coaching has given me the time to think about what I really wanted to achieve and how I can make it happen. I have been completely blown away by how much I have enjoyed coaching with Becky and embraced the concept across my whole life."<br />
    <small>Caroline Rowe, <br />
    Communications Manager</small></p>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: See http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please show some actual code. You're not really asking an answerable question here.

Comment: Also, what's with the testimonial paragraph....?

Comment: I don't see any problems with your code, so my question is this - do you actually have a page with a page slug of "about"?  Where are you trying to use this code?  In the page template?  In `index.php`?  In a sidebar?

Comment: sorry my mistake, new to this site...

the code is in my sidebar-custom.php and there is a slug called 'about' set up.

as for the paragraph thats just the testimonial that for the block that i want to appear on certain pages e.g. about and maybe one other page.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

fixed it! it put this in`<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>`

Comment: Make this a useful answer - **where** did you put the reset_query in your code (from the question)?

Answer (score 0):

the code looks fine.

the is_page() function does a case-sensitive string comparison ( i believe).

Check for the letter casing.. and see if it works.